# How to add padding/margin to icon of JavaFX8 TreeItem?

Tags: treeview, java-8, javafx-8, styling

I created a TreeView and added some TreeItem's with a customized icon. The icon is of Dimension 16x16 (taken from [FamFamFam](http://www.famfamfam.com/)). I read somewhere on SO that the preferred size is 9x9px.

So here is my code for Tree creation:

```
final Path folderImgPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("./resources/gui/folder.png");
Image folder = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(folderImgPath.toFile())), null);
ImageView tis = new ImageView(folder);

TreeItem<String> ti1 = new TreeItem<String>("Inbox2", tis);

TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String>("Inbox");
rootItem.getChildren().add(ti1);
rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Inbox3",  new ImageView(folder)));
rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Inbox4",  new ImageView(folder)));
```

the icon 'folder.png' appears next to the TreeItem in the TreeView as expected but what i wanna do and dont know how to do is to move the icon up by 2 pixels. Take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

The icon of Inbox2 and Inbox4 need some adjustment on the y - axis. I post processed the screenshot and moved the icon of Inbox3 up by 2 pixels. The red line shows the baseline of the cell label.

So can you help me to achieve this in code?

It would be possible to scale the icon down to 9x9 in code using:

```
ImageView tis = new ImageView(folder);
tis.setFitWidth(9);
tis.setFitHeight(9);
```

than it would be centered on the y-axis but the size is just too small for FamFamFam icons.
Another option would be to make the font bigger but again, i don't wanna do that either.

Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you can get rid of those Swing methods to load the images:

```
ImageView tis=new ImageView(
       new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/gui/folder.png")));
```

Then you can wrap the image view with an `HBox`, align the image at the top of it, and play with the desired height till you have the effect you're looking for (depending on the dimensions of the image and the font size):

```
HBox hTis=new HBox(tis);
hTis.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
hTis.setPrefHeight(20); // <-- Adjust this value

TreeItem<String> ti1 = new TreeItem<>("Inbox2",hTis);
...
```